# Force cxf-codegen-plugin to use existing generated classes instead of creating new ones

Tags: java, web-services, maven, xsd, wsdl

I have a set of XSD (A and B) and their corresponding Java classes are generated by maven-jaxb2-plugin. Java classes are in package P1.

Beside, I have a WSDL which uses some types from XSD A and B.

However, when I generate Java classes from my WSDL with cxf-codegen-plugin, it generates types in package P2.

==> Types in P1 and P2 are strictly identicals.

My question is: how can I tell cxf-codegen-plugin to use existing package P1?

Thanks!

Hejk